# Is CR LF in PHP scripts compatible with unix servers?

Tags: php, unix, iis, newline, eol

If a PHP script is created with CRLF (\r\n) EOL, and is transferred in binary mode to a unix OS, would there be any issues or is a \r\n PHP script compatible to be executed on a unix web server?

What about vice versa? A unix LF (\n) PHP script that is on a windows IIS server. Any issues with this?

Comment: absolutely fine. that \r\n or \n choice only changes appearance of code in text editor

Comment: then why does ASCII mode exist for PHP files?

Comment: I`m not sure ASCII mode is related to line endings